# updatedAt column is not updated with latest datetime while sending a put request

Tags: mysql, express, axios, sequelize.js

While sending an `put` request, the `dailystatus` column alone gets updated with the data, but the `updatedAt` column is left behind without updating the latest date/time. During the post, the date and time automatically inserted in createdAt and updatedAt column, so while sending a put req, should we need to send instruction to update the updatedAt column, if so how can we do that ?

//This is to update `dailystatus` and `updatedAt` column in the availability table:

```
`server.js`

    app.put('/service/availability', async (req, res) => {
    
      try {
        const userEmail = req.query.email;
        const dailyStatus =  req.body.dailystatus;
        var selector = {
          where: { email: userEmail }
        };
        var updateData = {dailystatus:dailyStatus};
        const playerDailyStatus = await Availability.update(updateData, selector);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
      } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
      }
    });
```

`Availability.js`

```
    const onUpdate = (dailyinput) =>{
      console.log("Here Daily:"+ dailyinput);
      const dailyStatus = async () => {
          try {
              const params = {
                  email: loginUserEmail,
              };
            const res = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/availability', { dailystatus: dailyinput }, {params} );
            console.log("Dailystatus update:" + res.data.success);
            if (res.data.success) {
              setDeleteDialog(false);
            }
            else {
              console.log(res.data.message);
              setHelperText(res.data.message);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
          }
        }
        dailyStatus();
  }
```

`availability.js` model

```
'use strict';
module.exports =  (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const availability = sequelize.define('availability', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false

        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(18)
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'availability'
    });
    availability.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        availability.belongsTo(models.user, {
            foreignKey: 'user_id',
            sourceKey: 'id',
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return availability;
}
```

Comment: use the default mysql behaviour [on timestamp initialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) in the table defination.

Comment: Ok, i have also added my availability.js model to the question, could you check if that looks good.

Comment: that only handles the creation time. The 'ON UPDATE'  needs to be incorporated somehow.

Answer (score 1):

just add it manually

```
var updateData = {
    dailystatus: dailyStatus,
    updatedAt: new Date(),
  };
```

or you can make hook like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports =  (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const availability = sequelize.define('availability', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false

        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(18)
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        }
    }, hooks: {
           beforeUpdate: (availability, options) => {
               availability.updatedAt = new Date();
       },
    },{
         timestamps: true,
         tableName: 'availability'
    });
    availability.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        availability.belongsTo(models.user, {
            foreignKey: 'user_id',
            sourceKey: 'id',
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return availability;
}
```